# sortBy() text doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, sorting

I have a function in Laravel framework witch parse `order` and sort `query`

```
private function parseOrder($order, $query)
    {
        $columns = explode(',', $order);
        foreach ($columns as $column) {
            if ($column[0] === '-') {
                $column = substr($column,1);
                $query->orderByDesc($column);
            } else {
                $query->orderBy($column);
            }
        }
    }
```

Function work correctly with `order` type int, but when I try use order type `string` function doesn't return data.

Example of data:

```
"id": 1,
        "title": "Corporis maxime vero aperiam labore ipsum laborum repudiandae.",
        "text": "Possimus enim modi nihil saepe atque cum. Est consequuntur ut commodi non dolores sint adipisci. Non voluptas consequatur nam ratione velit et deleniti. Corrupti rerum delectus voluptatem fugit.",
        "image_id": 24,
        "author_id": 24,
        "source_id": 1,
        "type_id": 1,
        "editor_text": "Esse labore odit voluptatum ea doloremque praesentium. Asperiores id voluptatem et voluptatem. Sequi sint expedita eum nam non pariatur ea. Deleniti ut magni nihil eveniet.",
        "recipe": "Recipe: Hatter. 'You might just as the other.' As soon as there seemed to be sure, she had never had fits, my dear, and that you couldn't cut off a head could be no chance of this, so that her neck from.",
        "recipe_link": "http://www.bradtke.net/",
        "count_recipe_link_redirect": 998,
        "recommended_at": "2017-08-16 12:28:21",
        "created_at": "2017-08-17 13:13:44",
        "updated_at": "2017-08-17 13:13:44",
        "deleted_at": null
```

Comment: Show your table schema and exactly what you're passing into `$order`.

Comment: Is `$column` a string or an array?  You are treating it as both, eg first `$column[0]` and then `substr($column,1)`.

Comment: Add data example, try passing fields title, text.

Comment: columns - array, column - string

Comment: If `$column` is meant to be a string, what is `$column[0]`?

Comment: Delete first sign which in this case '-'

Comment: Oh I see, I forgot you can do that with strings, sorry. OK so where is the code that does not work, I mean where is `parseOrder` invoked, and what parameters are you passing it?

Comment: I call it when show list of post. Param: array of post (example in top) and order 'text'.

Comment: But when order 'id' - all work correctly .